# How to enable just one more turn?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I just started playing the new Civilization. I tried a new game and after losing, I cannot click on the just one more turn button. And I had the same problem after I tried to setup my own game. Even in advanced option I cant find how to enable this function. I haven't had this problem with previous Civilization games.

Comment: I've had the button (and it worked) after winning my first game. Maybe you just don't have it if you lose?

Comment: When you lose you generally can't continue playing...

Comment: @Shadur Don't you normally get the button if you lose through someone else winning (as opposed to actually being defeated)?

Comment: I had the button and it worked fine for me when I won the mind flower victory.... Maybe if you lose you can't do it?

Comment: You could save your game once in a while and when you lose, just backup the last saved game. There's also "autosaves" tab in "Load Game" which saves your game every 10-20 turns.

Answer (score 9):

You can only click the "Just...One...More...Turn" button when you've won the game.